# How to reliably change the fill colour of a rectangle using an animation timeline via PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, fill

I am coding using PowerPoint VBA, but am having difficulties trying to reliably change the fill colour of a shape (rectangle) using an animation timeline and msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor. What happens is on the first occasion the affect works as intended, but doing a repetition on the same shape (normally the second or third run) results in the replacement colour changing to an alternative undesired colour (normally orange). I believe this is easy to replicate.

If you create a PowerPoint and insert a filled rectangle and run the below macro (such as when the rectangle is clicked on) - the first click changes to the intended colour (here red). However, if you keep running the macro the colour (eventually) changes to orange! I would be grateful if anyone could explain why this happens and if there is a solution then please let me know! The other observation I have made is that often I have to reset the project in the Visual Basic Editor for the animation to start working again.

```
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim oeff As Effect
Dim MyDocument As Slide

Sub rectangle()

'I don't know if we need this first bit of code but it removes any existing animations on the current timeline'
Dim i As Integer
For i = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence(1).Delete
Next i

'This is the code to create the animation.
Set MyDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set oshp = MyDocument.Shapes("Rectangle 3")
Set oeff = MyDocument.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect _
(Shape:=oshp, effectid:=msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
oeff.EffectParameters.Color2.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
oeff.Timing.Duration = 0.25
oeff.Timing.TriggerDelayTime = 0.5

End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't tried you code yet, but it's always good to Set your objects to Nothing at the end of the macro.

Comment: John Korchok - thank you for comment. I think you are stating that I should add the line: Set MyObject = Nothing. I shall give this a try! I have only been coding with VBA for about two weeks now and am self-learning as I go along. So I apologise if ther is anything basic that I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

I am please to write that I have found the answer to my question and it might be useful for other persons. The solution is to declare the variables inside the Sub. I am not sure there is a rule that says that this has to always be the case. So the code looks like this:

```
Sub rectangle()

Dim oshp As Shape
Dim oeff As Effect
Dim MyDocument As Slide

'This first bit of code removes any existing animations on the current
'timeline and is not part of the animation.
Dim i As Integer
For i = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence(1).Delete
Next i

'This is the code to create the animation.
Set MyDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set oshp = MyDocument.Shapes("Rectangle 3")
Set oeff = MyDocument.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect _
(Shape:=oshp, effectid:=msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
oeff.EffectParameters.Color2.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
oeff.Timing.Duration = 0.25
oeff.Timing.TriggerDelayTime = 0.5

End Sub
```

Comment: I was about to comment on the question, asking you to clean up your variable declarations - I did not expect that this would change anything, but it's bad practice to have global variables and it seemed completely unnecessary here. Two sanity tips for your VBA code: 1) Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules. No exceptions. 2) Turn all global (module-level) variables into local (function-level) ones, unless there really is no other way (happens, but is extremely rare).

Comment: Completely agree with Option Explicit. It makes debugging so much easier, especially if you're subject to typos. Variables can be declared within a procedure, at the module level or globally for a project. All are valid in specific use cases but if you only use them inside a procedure then that's where they should be declared. Module level is very common for multi-procedures in a module. For complex multi-module projects, global variables such as Product_Name are common.